# Find number of ID's having status as 'R' among list of objects in Java

Tags: list, object

I have a list of objects where each object is having Id and status.
How can I find distinct number of ID's which are having all the status as 'R'?
For example:
Id         Status
5           R
1           S
5           R
2           R
1           R
5           R

In this case count of ID =2 because ID(5 and 2) are having status 'R'

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 it's pretty easy:

```
class Foo {
    int id;
    char status;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        return ( id == ((Foo) o).id ) && ( status == ((Foo) o).status );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return id << 8 + status;    // Example, supposing id is not too big
    }
}

List<Foo> list;

int result = Stream.of(list).distinct().filter(x -> x.status == 'R').count();
```

First you convert you `List` of `Foo` into a `Stream` of `Foo`, then you eliminate duplicates, you filter your elements depending on the value of the status field. Finally you count the remaining elements.

To correctly eliminate duplicates you have to overload `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Comment: We do not have java 8 in our framework.Is there any other method?

Comment: @Vincz77 add a .distinct() before count. There's duplicate items in the example. And let's hope equals and hashcode have been defined in the Foo class :)

Answer (score 0):

With Java <= 7, it's just basics programming.

```
    Set<Integer> match = new HashSet<>();
    for (Item item : myList) {
        if (item.status=='R') match.add(item.id);
    }
    System.out.println(match.size());
```

I put all matching Id in a Set to count duplicates only once.

Comment: You are putting an id to Set if its status is 'R'. What if it's status is not 'R' ? We have to exclude that item.